# Unable to extract a substring from a string

Tags: c#, .net, substring

I am long string array and i want to pass it to another function in the chunks of `250` characters one time, i have written this code:

```
var cStart = 0;
var phase = 250;
var cEnd = cStart + phase;
var count = 0;

while (count < 10000)
{
    string fileInStringTemp = "";
    fileInStringTemp = fileInString.Substring(cStart, cEnd);
    var lngth = fileInStringTemp.Length;

    //Do Some Work

    cStart += phase;
    cEnd += phase;
    count++;
}
```

In the first iteration of the loop the value of `lngth` is `250` which is fine, in the next iteration i also want it to `250` because i am extracting substring from 250-500 characters but shockingly the value of `lngth` variable in the second iteration gets `500`.

Why is that? i am also trying to initialize string variable everytime in the loop so it starts from zero but no gain.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Substring's second parameter is the length you want](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aka44szs%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), not the stop index.

```
public string Substring(
    int startIndex,
    int length
)
```

So, all you need to do is change your code to have the start index and length (`phase`)

```
fileInString.Substring(cStart, phase)
```

Answer (score 7):

Here is the MSDN link about how to work with Substring:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aka44szs(v=vs.110).aspx

According to MSDN first parameter in Substring method is StartIndex which is defined as **The zero-based starting character position of a substring** and second parameter is used to define lenght of substring which is defined as **The number of characters in the substring**.

So you should try this:

```
var cStart = 0;
var phase = 250;
var count = 0;

while (count < 10000)
{
    string fileInStringTemp = "";
    fileInStringTemp = fileInString.Substring(cStart, phase);
    var lngth = fileInStringTemp.Length;

    //Do Some Work
    count++;
    cStart = phase * count + 1;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try changing

```
fileInStringTemp = fileInString.Substring(cStart, cEnd);
```

to

```
fileInStringTemp = fileInString.Substring(cStart, cPhase);
```

Answer (score 0):

Substring has the parameters (`startIndex, count)` so you are not aloud to increment end. better change to `Substring(cStart, phase)`

Answer (score 0):

The 2nd parameter to your SubString() method is the length of the substring to return.  (You should be able to always use 250 and just keep shifting your starting point - the 1st param - until you are done.)